# Converting an HTML file to PDF doesn't add the text to the new PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

My goal is to convert an HTML file to PDF. The conversion worked and preserved the layout but the text is not added in the converted PDF file and I don't know why.

**Here's the code I used to convert HTML to PDF:**

```
// Add the --enable-local-file-access option to enable access to local files (HTML)
$wkhtmltopdfCommand = "wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access ar-11.html ar-11.pdf";
exec($wkhtmltopdfCommand);
```

For your information, I obtained the HTML file from a PDF file that I converted into an HTML file. This PDF file is government-secured and contains no password.

**How can you help me add the text, please?**

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your HTML it is supposed to be filled by real people who enter their data, like this HTML from PDF, the data is then stored in their HTML copy (same as if in their local PDF copy)

```
required="required" maxlength="30" value="Simpson" data-objref="295 0 R" title="Information About You.`
```

[image]

[image]

After digital signing, then they can "Printout" to PDF their personal submission. NOTE:- the tooltip specifically says they need to print and sign in inked format (Digital inked as shown should be OK) as full electronic encrypted signature is NOT acceptable for submittal.
[image]
[image]

So printing with wkhtml or user press print is the same the text must be selectable entries.

[image]
[image]

There are other ways to use a server online to PDF>XML<PDF but although this looked partly OK it was a serious fail for me in other areas of that form, so will not embarrass the site owners by name.

[image]

The simplest method of all is export FDF from source PDF then edit and import to print. However that form requires a commercial grade Adobe live cycle server or equivalent to start off with.

Comment: @K J It didn't help me. I don't want to use any third party pay services. Can you give me a piece of code so it can work?